# How to open an android device on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: android, 19.04, samsung

I am trying to connect a Samsung Galaxy A8 on my Ubuntu laptop. Despite, after several attempts, I managed to open the files on the device, the interface us extremely slow.

Do you have any advice on it? Can it be the brand of the cable (not the Samsung original one)

Best
Giulio

Answer (score 0):

The cable *might* make a difference but don't quote me on it. I have a Samsung J5 and I too find it slow when connecting so I think it's more to do with the phone than any issue with your operating system.  Mine is just as slow when I'm connected to a Windows PC or laptop.

One thing that can be quicker is if you have the files you want to view or edit on a micro SD card. Just unmount it from the phone, slot it into a suitable adapter and plug it straight into your laptop.